# vehicle route problem with pick up and delivery

Tags: algorithm, graph, vehicle-routing

I have been digging google for 2 days looking for an explanation for algorithm that solve the pick up and delivery variant of the vehicle route problem, but, I could not find, so please either someone give me an example or point me to some resources preferably with worked examples in them.

I cam across something called saving algorithm, but could not find any resource on how to use it to solve pick up and delivery variant.

Comment: You are probably looking at a variation of the travelling salesman problem, and is likely a problem in NP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many variants of the vehicle routing problem, so I wouldn't be surprised if there's no tutorial material for this particular one.

If you're not comfortable with constraint programming, I'd suggest the Biased Random Key Genetic Algorithm (BRKGA) framework, which has tutorial material and several implementations. A BRKGA genome is a vector of numbers between zero and one, and the framework defines all operations on genomes except for the one that decodes a genome into a feasible solution, which can be composed with the objective function to compute fitness.

In general there is an art to choosing a good decoder. For this problem I would try this first. Define the vector length to be the number of stops (pickup or delivery). To determine the order of stops, initialize a priority queue with all of the pickups, where the genome determines the priorities. Until the queue is empty, pop the max priority stop and schedule it next. If it's a pickup, add the corresponding delivery to the queue.

Comment: would you please point me to some tutorials for the algorithm you suggested?

Comment: @mark15987 http://mauricio.resende.info/talks/2012-09-CLAIO2012-brkga-tutorial-both-days.pdf https://pymoo.org/algorithms/brkga.html https://www.codementor.io/@marcelofa/an-introduction-to-the-brkga-mp-ipr-algorithm-17qpq645gk